# Chrome not caching <object> requests

Tags: google-chrome, http, caching

I am creating HTML object with onload event, that creates another copy of it with the same svg image path.

```
<object data="/image.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

I have set Expires and Cache-Control headers, to prevent double loading. However, chrome ignores them and doesn't use cached image from previous request, like other browsers do. Directly requests to this image are cached, so I guess there is a problem only with  requests caching.

**Response Headers of the second request:**

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:59
Cache-Control:max-age=1200
Content-Length:267155
Content-Type:image/svg+xml
Date:Tue, 14 Nov 2017 08:16:05 GMT
ETag:"842401d-41393-5598c11d4b740"
Expires:Tue, 14 Nov 2017 08:36:05 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 19 Sep 2017 14:56:53 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.17 (Fedora)
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was, that if you are using proxy, chrome does not show you "from disk cache" message in developer tools. But it actually does. I had to use low internet speed connection settings to find out the real result.